# Unique linear combination problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $S$ a subset of $V$ with the property that whenever $v_1,v_2,\ldots v_n\in S$ and $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots a_nv_n=0$, then $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_n=0$. Prove that every vector in the span of $S$ can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of the vectors of $S$.

My attempt: Let $v\in Span(S)$.

$\Rightarrow v= a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots a_nv_n$

If $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots a_nv_n=0$, then $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_n=0$ and the linear combination is unique.

What about when $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_n\neq 0$?

I can see that in this case $v$ is the linear combination of some $v_i$'s such that not all $a_i$'s are zero. How do I prove the uniqueness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it, assuming you have two linear combinations.

(If you want the whole demonstration, ask it in comment, will edit.)

Comment: Why by contradiction? It's a direct proof.

Comment: Ok, then I'll assume that $v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n$ and $v=b_1v_1+b_2v_2+\ldots+b_nv_n$. So $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n=b_1v_1+b_2v_2+\ldots+b_nv_n$. So $(a_1-b_1)v_1+\ldots+(a_n-b_n)v_n$=0. Which gives $a_i-b_i=0$ and so $a_i=b_i$. Am i correct? And thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, correct. Well done.

Comment: @egreg In my mind that is by contradiction because you assume that you have two different combinations but you conclued that it's not possible. But indeed, you can assume that you have two linear combinations and conclued that they are the same, that's more logic maybe. :)

Comment: @Deuteu The attempted proof uses no contradiction, does it?

Comment: @egreg As i said, it's depend on how you start that.
You can start by taking two different combinations and showing that's isn't possible. You can also start by taking two combinations and showing there are equal. Diya used the second one (and I think this is the more logic one, that's why I edited my answer).

Comment: I think what Deuteu meant is we start with two combinations and prove that they are indeed the same. :)

Comment: @Deuteu What Diya presented is a common method of proof, but technically it would be a proof by contradiction if and only if one starts out by saying, for example in this case, "assume that $a_i\ne b_i$ for some ${i=1,2,\;...\;,n}$". Because then you will proceed to find the contrary.