# Every vector in the span can be written as a unique linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

This exercise is from my textbook:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $S$ an non-empty subset of $V$ with the property that whenever $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n \in S$ and $a_1v_1 + \cdots a_nv_n=0$ then $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$. Prove that every vector in the span of S can be uniquely written as a linear combination of elements of $S$

I found the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915727/unique-linear-combination-problem), but the answer is incomplete, this is quite easy if S is finite, the problem arises when S is infinite. Let $w\in span(S)$ then there exist a finite number of elements in S, $u_1, \dots, u_n \in S$ and scalars $a_1, \dots, a_n \in F$ such that $w= a_1u_1+\cdots+ a_nu_n$, if there exists another linear combination equal to $w$, then there exist vectors $e_1,\dots e_m \in S$ and scalars $b_1, \dots, b_m \in F$ such that $w=b_1v_1 + \cdots + b_mv_m$, but not necessarily $n=m$ and $u_1=e_1, \dots u_n=e_n$, at this point, I don't know exactly how to proceed to prove that the liner combination is unique.

Edit: The definitions of linear combination and span of a set that the author gives are the following

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $S$ be a non-empty subset of $V$, a vector $v\in V$ is a linear combination of elements of $S$ if there exist a finite number of vectors $u_1, \dots, u_n \in S$ and scalars $a_1, \dots, a_n \in F$ such that $v=a_1u_1 + \cdots+ a_nv_n$

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $S$ be a non-empty subset of $V$, we define $span(S)$ as the set $$span(S) := \{v\in V : v \ \text{is a linear combination of elements of} \ S\}$$

Comment: Actually the possibility that $S$ is infinite doesn't matter.   Linear combinations are always finite expressions.

Comment: This is a purely notational problem, not a conceptual one. Look at your vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ and $e_1,\ldots,e_m$. By reordering if necessary, we may assume that $u_1=e_1,\ldots,u_r=e_r$, and $u_j\neq e_j$ if $j\gt r$. Then rewrite $w$ as $w=a_1u_1+\cdots a_nu_n + 0e_{r+1}+\cdots + 0e_{m}$ and as $w=b_1e_1+\cdots+b_re_r+0a_{r+1}+\cdots + 0a_{n} + b_{r+1}e_{r+1}+\cdots + b_me_m$.

Comment: Alternatively, show that $S$ has the desired property if and only if every *finite* subset of $S$ has the desired property, and work in $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}\cup\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}\subseteq S$.

Comment: Note that you introduce vectors $e_i$ in your second linear combination, but then express it in terms of vectors $v_j$ that were never defined; I had fixed that, but you unfixed it when you edited to add the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That every vector can be written as a linear combination of vectors of $S$ is given by your definition of $\text{span}(S)$.

Now, for the uniqueness you can proceed by induction.

Suppose $w \not=0$ and $w=a_1 u_1=b_1v_1 + \cdots + b_mv_m$, then
$$a_1 u_1 -b_1v_1 - \cdots - b_mv_m=0 \hspace{5mm} (1)$$
Now, if $u_1 \not = v_i$ for all $i=1, \cdots, m$, then by your assumptions we get that $a_1=b_1= \cdots=b_m=0$, so $w=0$ getting a contradiction. Then, we must have that $u_1=v_i$ for some $i$ (suppose wlog that $i=1$), and by $(1)$ we get
$$(a_1-b_1)v_1 - b_2v_2 - \cdots - b_mv_m=0$$
so $a_1=b_1$ and $b_2=\cdots=b_m=0$ and we get the uniqueness.

Suppose then that the uniqueness is true for every vector $u \in \text{span}(S)$ that can be written as a linear combination of $n$ vectors in $S$, and let $w=a_1u_1+\cdots+a_n u_n +a_{n+1}u_{n+1}=b_1v_1 + \cdots + b_mv_m$.

Observe then that
$$a_1 u_1 +\cdots+a_n u_n +a_{n+1}u_{n+1} -b_1v_1 - \cdots - b_mv_m=0 \hspace{5mm} (2)$$
So, if every $u_i$ is dinstinc from every $v_j$, as before we get $w=0$ which is a contradiction. Then, wlog we get that $v_1=u_1$, and from $(2)$
$$(a_1-b_1) u_1 +\cdots+a_n u_n +a_{n+1}u_{n+1} -b_2v_2 - \cdots - b_mv_m=0 \hspace{5mm} (3)$$
As every $u_i$ with $i>1$ is different from $u_1$ and every $v_j$ with $j>1$ is different from $v_1=u_1$, we get from $(3)$ that $a_1=b_1$, and then that
$$a_2u_2+\cdots+a_n u_n +a_{n+1}u_{n+1}=b_2v_2 + \cdots + b_mv_m$$
Now, we have that $w'=a_2u_2+\cdots+a_n u_n +a_{n+1}u_{n+1}$ is a linear combination of $n$ vectors of $S$, so by the induction hypothesis we have that (after some possible rearrangement) $m=n+1$, $u_j=v_j$ and $a_j=b_j$ for $j=2, \cdots, n+1$, which concludes the induction.

EDITED: As explained by Arturo Magidin in his answer, in the prove is supposed that $w \not = 0$ and that the vectors $v_i$ and $u_j$ are pairwise distinct (between them) and not null.

Answer (score 3):

Note that there is a "pairwise distinct" missing in your original exercise: the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are assumed to be **pairwise distinct**. Otherwise, the assumption is never met, since taking $v_1=v_2$ be any vector in $S$, we can look at $1v_1-1v_2$.

Also, "unique expression" in the conclusion has to include a caveat that you are allowed to add summands of the form $0\mathbf{x}$ with arbitrary $\mathbf{x}$. Otherwise, if $S$ has more than one element then you *never* have uniqueness, since given $s_1,s_2\in S$, $s_1\neq s_2$, you could take $s_1 = 1s_1$, and also $s_1=1s_1+0s_2$ and they would be "different" (but not really). So we are allowed to add summands with other vectors if they are multiplied by $0$.

The key is that if you have two expressions
$$ v=a_1u_1+\cdots + a_nu_n = b_1v_1+\cdots + b_mv_m,$$
with $u_i,v_j\in S$, the $u_i$ pairwise distinct, the $v_j$ pairwise distinct, we can rewrite both expressions so that we use the exact same (finite) number of vectors.

If the two lists of vectors are the same after reordering (clearly the order is immaterial), then this is easy. We have:
$$\begin{align*}
v &= a_1u_1+\cdots + a_nu_n\\
&= b_1u_1+\cdots +b_nu_m,
\end{align*}$$
(because we are assuming $n=m$, and $u_1=v_1,\ldots,u_n=v_n$); taking the difference we get
$$\begin{align*}\mathbf{0} = v - v &= (a_1u_1+\cdots+a_nu_n) - (b_1u_1+\cdots +b_mu_m)\\
&= (a_1-b_1)u_1 + \cdots + (a_n-b_n)u_n,
\end{align*}$$
from which we get $a_i-b_i=0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, so $a_i=b_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

What if they are *not* the same list? Well, maybe *some* of the vectors are the same. So let us reorder the list so they both start with $x_1,\ldots,x_r$, and then we have $u_{r+1},\ldots,u_n$ and $v_{r+1},\ldots,v_m$, with $x_1,\ldots,x_r,u_{r+1},\ldots,u_n$ pairwise distinct, $x_1,\ldots,x_r,v_{r+1},\ldots,v_{m}$ pairwise distinct, and $u_{r+1},\ldots,u_n,v_{r+1},\ldots,v_m$ pairwise distinct. Proceeding as above, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
v &= a_1x_1+\cdots + a_rx_r + a_{r+1}u_{r+1}+\cdots + a_nu_n\\
&= b_1x_1+\cdots +b_rx_r + b_{r+1}v_{r+1}+\cdots + b_{m}v_m.
\end{align*}$$
Then taking the difference we get
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{0} = v - v & = (a_1x_1+\cdots + a_rx_r + a_{r+1}u_{r+1}+\cdots + a_nu_n)\\
&\qquad -
(b_1x_1+\cdots +b_rx_r + b_{r+1}v_{r+1}+\cdots + b_{m}v_m)\\
&= (a_1-b_1)x_1+\cdots + (a_r-b_r)x_r + a_{r+1}u_{r+1}+\cdots + a_nu_n\\
&\qquad -b_{r+1}v_{r+1}-\cdots - b_mv_m.
\end{align*}$$
Then we conclude that:

1. $a_1-b_1=\cdots=a_r-b_r=0$,
2. $a_{r+1}=\cdots=a_{n}=0$,
3. $b_{r+1}=\cdots=b_{m}=0$.

But that means that the two expressions are the same, except for possibly extra summands where each vector is multiplied by $0$ (and which therefore don't really "count"). Which is what we wanted to prove.

---

An alternative approach is to finite-fy everything.

**Lemma.** A nonempty subset $S$ has the property that

> for every finite collection of pairwise distinct vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in S$, if $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n = 0$, then $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$

if and only if every **finite** subset $S_0$ of $S$ has the property.

**Lemma.** Let $S$ be a nonempty set of vectors. Then $S$ has the property that

> Every $s\in\mathrm{span}(S)$ can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of pairwise distinct vectors in $S$, except perhaps for the order and extra summands of the form $0v$

if and only if every finite subset $S_0$ of $S$ has the property.

Proving these is not difficult. Then you can use the finite case to deal with the general case, since if $v=a_1u_1+\cdots+a_nu_n = b_1v_1+\cdots b_mv_m$, then it is all happening in the finite subset $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}\cup\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$.

Comment: Why do you say "pairwise distinct" instead of more simply "distinct"? Is there any difference?

Comment: @user24096 "distinct" may be interpreted as "not all the same". "pairwise distinct" means "no two are the same".

Comment: @user24096 in math, precision and precluding potential misinterpretation trump simplicity every day, and twice on Sundays.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a vector space and $S$ be a set of vectors in $V$.

$S$ is linearly independent iff every finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent i.e $0$ vector has a unique finite linear combination ( all coefficients are $0$)

Let $U=\textrm{span}(S) $. Since $S$ span $U$ and $S$ is linearly independent, hence $S$ is basis( Hamel basis/ algebraic basis) of $U$.

Every vectors of $U$ is a unique finite linear combination of vectors in $S$.

Comment: You are invoking the result that the OP wants to prove in order to prove the result that the OP wants to prove, but fancying it up with terminology. What the OP wants to show is that if $S$ is linearly independent, then every element of its span can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of elements of $S$. Your argument is that this holds because it holds.